# How to skip gpg signing for Java Maven project in Travis-CI

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I have a maven project in Travis CI and the build fails with

```
gpg: keyring `/home/travis/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/home/travis/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
```

So I changed my `.travis.yml` to

```
language: java
sudo: false
script: mvn clean verify -Dgpg.skip=true
```

which runs locally on my machine fine and skips the signing process of the jar.

But travis still fails with the message above.

Anyone an idea what to change to skip the jar signing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.
-Dgpg.skip doesn't seem to work even on my local machine (tested on Mint).
As a temporary workaround you can place configuration.skip in your maven gpg plugin properties.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
      --->          <skip>true</skip>  <---
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

For an release, you have to set skip to false manually.